# Running roundcube alongside passenger on nginx

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger, configuration, roundcube

I have recently tried to install passenger on nginx. The installation works and everything is good. However I would like to run roundcube webmail on my server as well.

Basically my problem is that nginx has the root directive set to the passenger app:

```
root /home/me/www/hello/public
```

and roundcube is created as a symlink on the server as:

```
/home/me/www/webmail
```

My question how do I get the url www.my-server.com to refer to the normal root but www.my-server.com/webmail to refer to the roundcube folder?

I have tried variations on the following in my nginx.conf with no luck:

```
location /webmail/ {
    #root /home/me/www;
    alias /home/me/www;
    try_files $uri /index.php;
    passenger_enabled off;
}
```

The above configuration results in 403 forbidden when using www.my-server.com/webmail and File not found when using the URI: www.my-server.com/webmail/index.php.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a bit tricky but I found the solution in the [nginx documentation about location](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location).

As there is a location directive matching .php files this will take precedence over the /webmail/ location and since this does not declare a root location the global root will be used which still points to the passenger folder.

The solution was to add a root directive to the php matching location and limit php execution to the webmail path, like so:

```
index index.html index.htm index.php

location /webmail/ {
    root /home/me/www;
}

location ~ /webmail/.*\.php$ {
    root /home/me/www;
    ...
}
```

Now everything works.